# Using Mongoose and Typescript, what type should be used for a ref field of an interface?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am using mongoose and Typescript, and I am wanting to know what type, or types, I should be using for a reference field, when creating an interface? Consider the following two related interfaces:

```js
interface ICat {
  name: string,
  colour: string,
}

interface ICatDB extends ICat, Document {};
```

```js
interface IMouse {
  name: string,
  colour: string,
  chasedBy: /* ... */
}

interface IMouseDB extends IMouse, Document {};
```

And the schemas and models that use them:

```js
let cat = new Schema({
  name: String,
  colour: String,
});

mongoose.model<ICatDB>('Cat', cat);
```

```js
let mouse = new Schema({
  name: String,
  colour: String,
  chasedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Cat' }
});

mongoose.model<IMouseDB>('Mouse', mouse);
```

For the `chasedBy` field we need to consider that it can take values in three forms:

- `String` or `ObjectId`, when passed to a `create()` method
- `ObjectId` when returned from Mongoose
- Instance of `ICat` when returned from Mongoose, using `populate()`

Is there a way that we can specify the types the interface can support, without having to resort to using `any`?

BTW we separated `IMouse` and `IMouseDB`, since Typescript wanted all the fields for `Document` filled out every time we created a new `IMouse` object, so this was a work around.

Comment: mongoose v7 improved the docs about TS types of populated documents.

Answer (score 8):

At least for version 5.x you could use this:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/typescript/populate.html

```
import { PopulatedDoc } from 'mongoose';
import ICat from './ICat';

interface IMouse {
  name: string,
  colour: string,
  chasedBy: PopulatedDoc<ICat>
}
```

The docs in 6.x shows different approach:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/populate.html
like this:

```
MouseModel.findOne({}).populate<{chasedBy: ICat}>('chasedBy');
```

Comment: Is PopulatedDoc still the best practice in the newest version of Mongoose? (`6.3.2`)

Comment: @winklerrr i don't know yet. but its in the official documentation of `6.3.2`.

Comment: When visiting the link you posted, I need to switch back to version `5.x` to actually find `PopulatedDoc` on that site?!

Comment: @winklerrr you are right, i think mongoose 6+ has new typings. So the answer is at least for 5.x then. I correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Lacking any alternative answer, I went with:

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
import ICat from './ICat';

interface IMouse {
  name: string,
  colour: string,
  chasedBy: string | ObjectID | ICat
}
```

This describes the type variants for the 'chasedBy' property. As to whether this is the recommended approach, I can't say.

Comment: Two years laters; have you found any better solution? Thank you in advance and regards

Comment: I haven't, but I have also started avoiding populate, unless necessary due to performance hits.

Comment: This is still an issue. Unfortunately you have also to cast explicitly when working with collection of refs :/

Answer (score 2):

## Mongoose `6.x`

Mongoose offers type declarations in `mongoose.Types`

```js
interface Mouse { // important: don't use I in front of the name and don't extend Document
  chasedBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
}
```